# Google Maps - Insert map type select into div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a responsive map, with a filter layout on the right side.

When the map is on mobile size, this sidebar goes hidden, and all filters are compressed. With a simple button I can show and hide filters.

[image: Maps]

But I have a problem. The map type select is outside my filters div, and I want to put it into to hide it too.

How can I do it?

Comment: Is your question how to hide the map type selection control? Or do you want to show it only when the "Menu" button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is no API-based access to the DOMNodes which represent the built-in controls.

But you may try to find them in the document, currently this control does have the className `gm-style-mtc`, use `querySelector` to find it and `appendChild` to put it where you want to:

```
    //wait for the idle-event, it takes some time until the control
    //has been added to the document
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(mapInstance,'idle',function(){
      targetNode.appendChild(this.getDiv().querySelector('div.gm-style-mtc'));
    });
```

Sample(you'll also need to adjust some CSS-settings for the control):

```js
      function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.549, 13.425),
            noClear: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            }
          }),
          bar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(bar);

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
          document.getElementById('mtc')
            .appendChild(this.getDiv().querySelector('div.gm-style-mtc'));
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
       html,
       body,
       #map_canvas {
         height: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0
       }
       #sidebar {
         background: blue;
         padding: 6px;
         border-radius: 6px;
         color: #fff;
         position: absolute;
         top:40px !important;
       }
       #sidebar>* {
         display: none;
         font-size: 1.2em;
       }
       #sidebar.expanded>* {
         display: block !important;
       }
       #sidebar h3 {
         font-weight: bold;
         text-align: center;
         font-size: 1.5em;
         cursor: pointer;
         display: block !important;
         padding: 2px;
         margin: 2px;
       }
       #sidebar.expanded>h3:first-child {
         border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
       }
       #sidebar #mtc {
         min-width: 120px;
         text-align: center;
         padding-bottom: 10px;
       }
       #sidebar #mtc>div {
         position: relative !important;
         display: inline-block !important;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h3 onclick="this.parentNode.className=(this.parentNode.className=='expanded')?'':'expanded'">☰&nbsp; Menú</h3>

    <strong>Filter#1</strong>
    <strong>Filter#2</strong>
    <strong>Filter#3</strong>
    <div id="mtc"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

But I wouldn't suggest it, because the Markup of the controls is not guaranteed to be stable, when they change it(e.g. modify the className) it doesn't work anymore.

You better hide the built-in MapTypeControl and create your own.